# Тип указателя на член класса

Tags: c++

Какой тип имеет указатель на член класса? Другими словами, что нужно подставить здесь, чтобы работало? Очевидное `int*` не работает.

```
struct X {
    int x = 0;
};

template<class T, T value>
auto foo() { return *value; }

int main() {
    std::cout << foo</* какой тип? */, &X::x>();
}
```

Comment: Здесь нельзя ничего поставить "чтобы работало". Очевидно, что пока в вашей программе нет ни одного объекта, не может идти и речи о применении операции разадресования указателя `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатель на поле класса должен иметь тип `int X::*`, а чтобы приведенный код работал надо еще создать экземпляр класса `X`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int x = 0;
};

template<auto x_pointer, typename x_Class>
auto foo(x_Class & obj)
{
    return obj.*x_pointer;
}
// или так
template<int X::* x_pointer>
auto foo(X & obj)
{
    return obj.*x_pointer;
}

int main()
{
    X x{};
    std::cout << foo<&X::x>(x);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5ImiJhWXAM9QNt11)